# How to say to my boss "Please don't hurry and take your time."?

Tags: expressions

My boss writes me, that he will arrive later to the place we are supposed to meet. I wish to answer him

> Please don't hurry and take your time. I will wait as much as it will be necessary.

What would be the best way to express this English sentence in Japanese?  I tried my luck and have said the next sentence:

> 急がないで時間をご十分にとってください。

And for the second sentence, I was not sure, so I decided to express it in a little bit another way:

> ○○さんのご都合がよい時間にいつでもお会いできます。

How would you express this English sentence in Japanese?
And I also know, I have mistakes in my sentences, could you please point out, what is exactly wrong in them...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to show you one of the typical expressions for the situation. This is not the direct translation of your English.

> Please don't hurry and take your time.
>   "お急{いそ}ぎにならなくて結構{けっこう}です。ご自分{じぶん}のご都合{つごう}に合{あ}わせて来{き}てください。"
>   Please don't hurry. You can come at your convenience. (If you actually want to have your boss come on time or ASAP, you cannot use this expression.)
>
> I will wait as much as it will be necessary.
>   "私は、約束{やくそく}の場所{ばしょ}でお待{ま}ち致{いた}します。"
>   I'll wait for you the place of appointment.

Comment: "must X"の否定は"must not X"ではなく、"cannot X"になってしまう.